# Add custom numbering to Vuetify datatable rows

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a Vue.js project using Vuetify datatables. The tables display ranking lists of sports performances ordered from fastest to slowest.

I can add a simple (rank) numbering system using props.index - but how can I manipulate that for cases where two performances are equal? I need to either skip the number for that row or add an = sign ([as seen in this example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AimWK.png))

The following method works with a standard table in Vue js, but does not work inside a Vuetify data table using the props.item.xxx method.

Code I have used:

```
<tr v-for="(result, index) in resultsData" :key="index">

    <template v-if="resultsData[index-1]">
        <td v-if="result.time == resultsData[index-1].time></td>
            &nbsp;
        <td v-else>
            {{index + 1}}
        </td>
    </template>

    <template v-else>
        <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
    </template>

<tr>
```

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="indexedItems"
  :loading="loading"
  :expand="expand"
  item-key=id
  :rows-per-page-items="[50]"
>

  <v-progress-linear slot="progress" color="blue" indeterminate></v-progress-linear>

  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded" :key="props.item.id">

      <template v-if="resultsData[props.index-1]">
        <td v-if="result.time == resultsData[props.index-1].time></td>
            &nbsp;
        <td v-else>
            {{props.index + 1}}
        </td>
    </template>

    <template v-else>
        <td>{{props.index + 1}}</td>
    </template>

      <td>{{props.item.time | removeLeadZeros}} {{props.item.distHeight | removeLeadZeros}} {{props.item.points | removeLeadZeros}}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.wind }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.nameFirst }} {{ props.item.nameLast }} </td>
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.centreID }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.DOB }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.placing }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.competition }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.venue }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.date }}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
  <template slot="expand" slot-scope="props">
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>IAAF Standard 10.12 | {{ props.item.competition }}</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </template>

</v-data-table>

My Vuetify table setup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Vuetify, but assuming it doesn't do anything too unusual, I think you could just pass it a computed property rather than the raw `indexedItems`:

```
computed: {
    rankedItems() {
        const items = [];
        if (this.indexedItems.length > 0) {
            items[0] = this.indexedItems[0];
            items[0].rank = 1;
            for (let index = 1; index < this.indexedItems.length; index++) {
                items[index] = this.indexedItems[index];
                if (items[index].time === items[index - 1].time) {
                    items[index].rank = "";
                } else {
                    items[index].rank = index + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Note: This adds a `.rank` property to each item. I'm assuming that's okay.

Then in your template pass that computed property to the component:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="rankedItems"
  :loading="loading"
  :expand="expand"
  item-key=id
  :rows-per-page-items="[50]"
>
```

And just use the new `.rank` property directly.

```
<td>
  {{props.rank}}
</td>
```

If you really need a non-breaking space, you can use `v-html`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this solution works great and is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way you can do it in the `template`.
Take a look at the [example](https://codepen.io/Jubels/pen/GzMQBg). In the example if name is the same as previous name, the rank column would get a `=`.

In your code the columns would look something like this:

```
<td v-if="resultsData[props.index -1] && resultsData[props.index -1].name === props.item.time">=</td>
<td v-else>{{ props.index}}</td>
<td>{{props.item.time | removeLeadZeros}} {{props.item.distHeight | removeLeadZeros}} {{props.item.points | removeLeadZeros}}</td>
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.wind }}</td>
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.nameFirst }} {{ props.item.nameLast }} </td>
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.centreID }}</td>
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.DOB }}</td>
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.placing }}</td>
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.competition }}</td>
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.venue }}</td>
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.date }}</td>
```

Comment: NIce solution Jeremy - thanks! very clean and simple - worked just fine!